# String formatting "in-place"

Tags: python

I have strings (list of str) containing placeholders `{}` and want to include variable values into those placeholders. One example of such a string could be `'test_variable = {}'`.
I need to find the index within the list I want to deal with and replace the `{}` as described.

Currently, the code looks like this with `find_occurrence_in_str_list()` being a simple function that returns the first occurrence of the search string in the list:

```
def find_occurrence_in_str_list(lines, findstr, start_index=0):
    for i in range(start_index, len(lines)):
        if findstr in lines[i]:
            return i

# Examples
variable_value = 10
strlist = ['example = {}', 'test_variable = {}']
# Code in question
index = find_occurrence_in_str_list(strlist, 'test_variable')
strlist[index] = strlist[index].format(variable_value)
```

This is totally fine. However, since I have a lot of such replacements, a better readability, especially a one-liner, would be desired instead of the last two lines. Currently, I just come up with this, which calls the search function twice and is not really more readable:

```
strlist[find_occurrence_in_str_list(strlist, 'test_variable')] = strlist[find_occurrence_in_str_list(strlist, 'test_variable')].format(variable_value)
```

Is there any way of formatting a string in-place instead of just returning the new string and needing to replacing it manually?

Comment: If your code works as intended, what really is the problem?

Comment: You can easily convert your: `Code in question` to a new function.

Comment: Your function can add a `value` parameter, then change `return i` to `lines[i] = lines[i].format(value)`. After that, you can just call `find_occurrence_in_str_list(strlist, 'test_variable', variable_value)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not simply return the already replaced string in my function because it shall be called from other code as well, which really just searches. And yes, I could convert it to another function but I am not sure if this improves readability. So it seems a format in-place is not available, i.e. I seem to not just miss anything here!?!

Comment: What should happen if you have two or more strings with the same findstr? Or is that not possible?

Comment: In my example it stops at the first occurrence and uses it, which is fine for this very dedicated piece of code because twice the same findstr will not appear. But of course, to generalize this one need to think about multiple or no occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of str.replace() and your function

```
def find_occurrence_in_str_list(lines, findstr,value, start_index=0):
for i in range(start_index, len(lines)):
    if findstr in lines[i]:
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace('{}', str(value))
        return lines

# Examples
variable_value = 10
strlist = ['example = {}', 'test_variable = {}']
# Code in question
strlist = find_occurrence_in_str_list(strlist, 'test_variable', variable_value)
```

Note: This will replace every `{}` in the string

Comment: This is a good idea. Not using format at all but replacing. The replacement value can be an optional parameter. If it is provided, the `{}` will be replaced. If not, the function just searches and returns the index. Thus, the behavior is pretty much like any find-function one knows from text editors etc.